# How to compare 2 csv files with > 1000 rows and find the difference?

Tags: python

I have a python script which scrapes a website and downloads some data in a csv file.

I run this script weekly. Now I want to compare 2 weeks csv and find which row has been changed in these 2 csv.

The data in the csv are 98% same with only 1 or 2 rows either gets added or deleted.

I am not able to get any proper solution. I used `DictReader` and tried to compare the content but no success.

Any pointers so solve might help, I also read that I can convert these to set and then do setA - setB

If it helps I will give a format of how CSV are.

file1.csv

```
name,userId,location
aaa,abc,NYC
bbb,cdf,UCL
```

file2.csv

```
name,userId,location
bbb,cdf,UCL
```

Now if you see, one row is deleted in file2.csv, so when i compare `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` I should be able to get the value `aaa,abc,NYC`

Comment: Need the solution in Python Code, I am already aware of diff and uniq commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, set difference works.

```
with open('file1.csv') as f, open('file2.csv') as g:
    old, new = set(f), set(g)
for added in new - old:
    print('added', added)
for deleted in old - new:
    print('deleted', deleted)
```

Comment: Any other option if possible. Because in future there might be some enhancements which Set will not offer. Also is this an efficient solution?

Comment: @archerimagine That's pretty efficient, yes. Expected linear time. Have you tried it? And what kind of enhancements?

Comment: This solution I have tried, and it works. Was not sure if changing it to **Set** and then using a set operation was an efficient solution, basically it solved the problem but did not felt like a solution.

Comment: Sets are pretty fast. Have a look at its table [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: Thanks for the links, looks like this is the solution then, will not break my head to get a efficient solution, because as per the link it will be **O(len(s))**

Answer (score 2):

Try the `diff` command:

```
diff file1.csv file2.csv
```

Depending on which OS you're using, you may need to find a copy that will work for your system.

Comment: Need the solution in python as I am learning Python. This option or, git diff or Beyond Compare or any other file compare will do this.

Comment: Did that, An that is the reason already mention on solution which is possible while asking the question **"can convert these to set and then do setA - setB"**

Comment: The canonical way to compare any data in lines of text records _is_ `diff`, but its algorithm has been implemented in many languages, including Python.  My quick search result included https://pypi.python.org/pypi/json-delta/ (a good exercise for you will be to convert the CSV data sets into JSON)

Comment: If I use a DictReader, to read the csv file, it will be a key/value pair, which is also a json?
json-delta 1.1.3 is a python package, wanted solution which I could code, even it does not handle all edge case.

Comment: @archerimagine then search for data differencing algorithms and implement them. Standard `diff` algorithms are quite fast if files are almost the same

Comment: JSON is an external text-format data representation with the potential of carrying much more meta-data than basic CSV records.  http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pandas` library for this.

**a.csv**

```
name,userId,location
aaa,abc,NYC
bbb,cdf,UCL
ccc,dfg,LAC
ddd,fgh,SAC
```

**b.csv**

```
name,userId,location
bbb,cdf,UCL
ccc,dfg,LAC
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
b = pd.read_csv('b.csv')

mask = a.isin(b.to_dict(orient='list'))
# Reverse the mask and remove null rows.
# Upside is that index of original rows that
# are now gone are preserved (see result).
c = a[~mask].dropna()
print c
```

**Result:**

```
  name userId location
0  aaa    abc      NYC
3  ddd    fgh      SAC
[Finished in 0.7s]
```

`pandas` has the upside of being optimized due to using a combination of `numpy`, `Cython`, and some raw C implementation here and there.

Answer (score 0):

If files are really that similar you can just compare lines between files.

I am using two sample files you posted in question.

```
file1 = []
file2 = []
with open('file1.csv','r') as f, open('file2.csv','r') as g:
    file1, file2 = list(f), list(g)

for line in file1:
    if line not in file2:
        print "Difference:",line
```

Output:

```
Difference: aaa,abc,NYC
```

## Update

I liked @Stefan Pochmann solution, and to me this would be the most elegant way:

```
with open('file1.csv','r') as f, open('file2.csv','r') as g:
    file1, file2 = set(f), set(g)
    print "Difference:", list(file1 - file2)
```

Comment: If I am correct this is an O(n^2) solution, can we do this in linear time? Even I remove the cost of reading the files in two for loops, which might be just one time cost.